# Proof using formal definition of limit that $ \lim_{x\to0} (x^2\sin(x^2+2x)+2)=2 $

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to prove the following, using the formal definition of limits:

$$
\lim_{x\to0} (x^2\sin(x^2+2x)+2)=2
$$

I already did the following the steps but I'm not sure if my thinking is correct:

$$
|x^2\sin(x^2+2x)+2-2|<\epsilon \implies  |x^2\sin(x^2+2x)|<\epsilon \implies |x^2||\sin(x^2+2x)|<\epsilon
$$

and assuming that $x\in{R}$ then $x^2|\sin(x^2+2x)|<\epsilon$

Now I also know that $-1<\sin(x)<1$ however I'm struggling to understand how to best apply this to the proof.

I'm not looking for a full solution to the problem, rather I'm interested in confirming if my thinking up until now is correct and maybe some hints to unblock the next steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there! Since the sine function is bounded by one and minus one, we have that
\begin{align*}
|x^{2}\sin(x^{2}+2x) + 2 - 2| = |x^{2}\sin(x^{2}+2)| \leq |x^{2}|\leq \varepsilon \Rightarrow |x|\leq\sqrt{\varepsilon}
\end{align*}

Thus we conclude that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds a $\delta = \sqrt{\varepsilon} > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
|x - 0| \leq \delta  = \sqrt{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |x^{2}| \leq \varepsilon & \Rightarrow |x^{2}\sin(x^{2} + 2x)| \leq |\sin(x^{2}+2x)|\varepsilon \leq \varepsilon  
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to find a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - 0| < \delta$ implies the inequality you are working on.  So you are trying to find an upper bound on $x$ in terms of $\varepsilon$.

You have more than $-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$.  You have $-1 \leq \sin(x^2 + 2x) \leq 1$.  So $0 \leq |\sin(x^2 +2x)| < 1$.  (The left-hand side of this is true for all moduli.  The right-hand side comes from the previous inequality.)  So you have
$$  x^2 [\text{some number in $[0,1]$}] < \varepsilon  \text{.}  $$
The biggest the left-hand side can be is $x^2$ and this gives a bound on $|x|$ in terms of $\varepsilon$...